# Angular Universal server express deployment to production errors

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

Hi I am getting always error in production when I try to deploy to webserver.
I am deploying everything to /var/myapp folder so basically in my server I have this paths:
/var/myapp/client/dist/client/browser folder where there is index.html and
/var/myapp/client/dist/client/server where there is the main.js file

I am running on server node /var/myapp/client/dist/client/server/main.js

Please help with the right configuration on server.ts file

```
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import 'localstorage-polyfill';

global.localStorage;
// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), '/var/myapp/client/dist/client/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.html')) ? 'index.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Angular universal deployment issue content is displayed but no css.
I am getting those errors:

```
runtime-es2015.3f64214655012374b6e0.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

polyfills-es2015.629687f397387c194377.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

main-es2015.a772fe1bf7606c343730.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```